# connecting to salesforce using only access_token with jersey

Tags: java, salesforce2salesforce

I am new in salesforce. I was ask to connect to salesforce using only token without the client_id, client_secret, username and password. I know that salesforce response different access_token everytime a request is sent.

is it possible to connect to salesforce without client_id and etc. I was ask to only use access_token and access_token is passed via java arguments.

how can I get access_token without sending request to salesforce?

or is there any other options for me to connect to salesforce without the client_id, client_secret, username and password?

Thank you!. sorry about my english.

```
Note: I am using jersey rest api.
```

Comment: Use any rest api, but without client_id, client_secret, username and password you cannot get access token without login to salesforce.

Comment: @regal is there any other options for me to connect to salesforce with just one token(whatever token).